# Converting model weight to torchscript, AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: flutter, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to convert my custom trained model's weight file into torchscript format for flutter app integration using the following script:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile
model = torch.load('best.pt',map_location="cpu")
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 640, 640)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
optimized_traced_model = optimize_for_mobile(traced_script_module)
optimized_traced_model._save_for_lite_interpreter("best_flutter.pt")
```

On running the script, it says

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Why is it so?

P.S I am running the script inside yolov5 master folder.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.load` function only loads the data that is stored in a file, it can be anything, and not specifically a model. Usually pytorch models are saved as a state dict, being a dictionary where keys are the layer names and values are tensors of weights. This is why you have a `dict` object in your `model` variable.

The normal way to use such a state dict is:

1. Load the dict in the file : `state_dict = torch.load(file)`
2. Create a model with uninitialized weights : `model = MyModel()` (adapt with the model effective name, it depends on the codebase you are using)
3. Load the weights from state dict to the model : `model.load_state_dict(state_dict)`

Some codebases also provide some wrappers to do the same kind of things, with maybe more parameters and features.